# Testing android native/driver code

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-ndk

I am going to change the android drivers (for example: "bluedroid" code).
I would like to understand how can I add unit test to check my changes.
Please  give an advise,Thanks in Advance

Comment: do you want to instrument your code?

Comment: What do you mean by "instrument your code"?

Comment: Have you looked at the README.txt file in the bluedroidtest folder?  I notice in several places there is use of a DUT (Device Under Test) flag.  I haven't used it myself, but it looks like a good place to start.